# How to send HTML message via Mimekit/Mailkit

Tags: c#, mailkit, mimekit

```
BodyBuilder bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
messageContent.Body = "<b>This is a test mail</b>";
bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = messageContent.Body;
```

I tried to embed my body to a bodybuilder but when I received the email, it returned an empty body. I have an exception that would throw an argument if the body is empty..

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Using a `BodyBuilder` like you are doing is probably the easiest way.

```
var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = "<b>This is some html text</b>";
bodyBuilder.TextBody = "This is some plain text";

message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();

client.Send(message);
```

Comment: If you only include `HtmlBody` and not `TextBody`, is there a risk that it could be identified as spam for only including one and not both?

Comment: That probably depends on the recipients mail software

Comment: More real world samples ?

Comment: Also, if the mail still shows in plain text, it could be due to the recipients mail software detects it as spam and converts it in plain text. E.g. Outlook does it.

Comment: @jstedfast How can we add multiple images to the body, not as an attachment

Comment: @jstedfast it shows plain text in 2 differnt recipients, i am following same

Answer (score 42):

[MimeKit Documentation - Creating Messages](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Creating-Messages.htm)

```
var message = new MimeMessage();    
message.Body = new TextPart ("html") { Text = "<b>Test Message</b>" };
```

"A TextPart is a leaf-node MIME part with a text media-type. The first argument to the TextPart constructor specifies the media-subtype: **plain**, **html**, **enriched**, **rtf**, and **xml**."

Comment: I was having a problem getting other examples to work.  This one went perfectly.  Thank you!

Answer (score 25):

One other option here if you want to be strict;

```
msg.Body = new TextPart(MimeKit.Text.TextFormat.Html) { Text = "<b>html content</b>" };
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var bodyBuilder = new BodyBuilder();
bodyBuilder.HtmlBody = body;
bodyBuilder.TextBody = "-";

message.Body = bodyBuilder.ToMessageBody();
```

**In some mail ISP, you should always set bodyBuilder.TextBody by value.**