# Error sending gmail using Google API

Tags: c#, google-api, gmail-api

I use the following code for sending emails to gmail by using **Google API**:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1;
using Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data;
using Google.Apis.Services;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System.Net.Mail;
using MimeKit;
using System.Configuration;


  class Program
    {
        static string credPath;
        static string credPath1;
        static string[] Scopes =
        {          
            GmailService.Scope.GmailModify,                      
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.compose",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.send",
            "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"             
        };      

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please Enter Your Mail Id");
                string usr = Console.ReadLine();
                UserCredential credential;
                using (var stream =
                new FileStream("client_secret.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                {
                    credPath =System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
                    credPath = Path.Combine(credPath, "credentials/gmail-dotnet-quickstart.json");            
                    credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync
                        (
                        GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                        Scopes,
                        "me",
                        CancellationToken.None,
                        new FileDataStore((credPath), false)
                        ).Result;

                }
                var gmail = new GmailService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential                    
                });


                var message = new MimeMessage();
            message.From.Add(new MailboxAddress("Saikam Nagababu", usr));
            message.To.Add(new MailboxAddress("Saikam Nagababu", "tomailid@gmail.com"));
            message.Subject = "How you doin?";
            message.Body = new TextPart("plain")
            {
                Text = @"Hey Alice"
            };


            var rawMessage = "";
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {

                message.WriteTo(stream);
                rawMessage = Convert.ToBase64String(stream.GetBuffer(), 0, (int)stream.Length)
                    .Replace('+', '-')
                    .Replace('/', '_')
                    .Replace("=", "");
            }
            var gmailMessage = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message { Raw = rawMessage };

            Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.UsersResource.MessagesResource.SendRequest request = gmail.Users.Messages.Send(gmailMessage, usr);
          request.Execute();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

                throw e;

            }
        }

        public static string Encode(string text)
        {
            byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(text);

            return System.Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
                .Replace('+', '-')
                .Replace('/', '_')
                .Replace("=", "");
        }      
    }
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> Google.GoogleApiException occurred
> HResult=-2146233088
> Message=An Error occurred, but the error response could not be deserialized
> Source=Google.Apis
> ServiceName=gmail
> StackTrace:
> at Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.<DeserializeError>d__34.MoveNext()
> InnerException: Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException
> HResult=-2146233088
> Message=Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0.
> Source=Newtonsoft.Json
> StackTrace:
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ParseValue()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadInternal()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.Read()
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType(JsonReaderreader, JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.Deserialize(JsonReaderreader, Type objectType, Boolean checkAdditionalContent)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeInternal(JsonReader reader,Type objectType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize(JsonReader reader, Type objectType)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Stringvalue, Type type, JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject[T](String value,JsonSerializerSettings settings)
> at Google.Apis.Json.NewtonsoftJsonSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
> at Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.<DeserializeError>d__34.MoveNext()
> InnerException:
> ```

Comment: Error says the response can't be deserialised, you need to figure out what is being sent back, perhaps using something like Fiddler.

Comment: @DavidG please suggest me what i need to deserialised.(like :gmail service object )how to deserialised by using Fiddler

Comment: I don't know what the response you are getting says, that's up to you to figure out. I was suggesting using Fiddler as a proxy to see the HTTP requests going between you and Google.

Comment: @Nagababu Which line in your code raise that error?

Comment: @TrungDuong i got error at : request.Execute();

Comment: I think the problem is on your message. I will  create an answer to explain more detail

Comment: @TrungDuong thank you  so much your response..

Answer (score 2):

I think you got the error because the gmail message that you create in your code have invalid format.

In your code, you try to convert *System.Net.Mail.MailMessage* to raw text. But when you call ToString on *MailMessage* object, it just returns a string that represents the object instance, not its content.

```
var gmailMessage = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message
                {  Raw = Encode(mailMessage.ToString())
                };
```

To convert *System.Net.Mail.MailMessage* to raw text, you could reference this link [Convert MailMessage to Raw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7515457/convert-mailmessage-to-raw-text).

I've not tried to convert *System.Net.Mail.MailMessage* to *Gmail*. But I've experienced converting *MimeKit.MimeMessage* to *Gmail*.

First, you create the [MimeMessage](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/CreatingMessages.htm)

```
var message = new MimeMessage ();
message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Joey", "joey@friends.com"));
message.To.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Alice", "alice@wonderland.com"));
message.Subject = "How you doin?";
message.Body = new TextPart ("plain") {
    Text = @"Hey Alice"
};
```

Then convert it to *Gmail* using the following codes

```
var rawMessage = "";
using (var stream = new MemoryStream ()) {

    message.WriteTo (stream);
    rawMessage = Convert.ToBase64String (stream.GetBuffer (), 0, (int) stream.Length)
        .Replace ('+', '-')
        .Replace ('/', '_')
        .Replace ("=", "");
}
var gmailMessage = new Google.Apis.Gmail.v1.Data.Message
                {  Raw = rawMessage };
```

Hope it could help.

Comment: it is not working ..i got same error..please suggest me

Comment: Which method are you using, MimeMessage or still System.Net.Mail.MailMessage?

Comment: what over  method you suggest me MimeMessage().

Comment: You are using MimeMessage and still get error, isn't it? As I could see in your question, your message is a html content. So instead create plain text MimeMessage, you should create  HTML MimeMessage. You could check this link for how to create a HTML  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41160536/how-to-send-html-message-via-mimekit-mailkit

Comment: what over your mention i copy paste and execute( i send plain text  ) ,but not working...

Comment: I have some doubts...shall i ask you..?

Comment: It's ok. You could ask me

Comment: from mail address you pass two parameter  first one is password and second one is mail id ..i am right? Ex: message.From.Add (new MailboxAddress ("Joey", "joey@friends.com"));

Comment: No, the first parameter is not password, it just a display name. I think if you could share your entire source code, I will try to figure out the problem.

Comment: i was updated my code in above section..please suggest me

Comment: My Modified code is shared top of above section ..please help me

Comment: I've created a test program, copy your code and replace your credential information with mine and it working normallly. I think the problem may be in your gmail account setting.  Did you follow the instructions at https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/dotnet?

Comment: i followed the same steps..please share your Client_screect file.

Comment: I've sent my credentials to email tomailid@gmail.com. But I think it could not help you much. If you use my credentials in your program,  when you run the program, it will open a consent screen and you will be prompted to log in with my google account. Have you registered your application for Gmail API in Google API Console?

Comment: yes..i registered ..my id: snagababusaikam@gmail.com...please share your credentials please..

Comment: I've shared my credential https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9kc0wx0qrxKNUltOEtuTVBuaDQ/view?usp=sharing Please check.

Comment: its asking request access please share to my mail id: snagababusaikam@gmail.com

Comment: i check your credentials My credential also same data in Client_screect file..my code got error..but my code execute in your side perfectly...please suggest me..

Comment: Could you send me your account information to email trungduong201608@gmail.com. I think I could help you check the setting of your account.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue regenerating the token, var "NewTOKEN_NAME" in the following example:

```
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream).Secrets,
                Scopes,
                "user",
                CancellationToken.None,
                new FileDataStore(NewTOKEN_NAME, true)).Result;
```